# How to set app title bar color using Theme.Material3.DayNight

Tags: android-jetpack-compose-material3

I can't find the way to change the purple title bar when app is in overview. I don't have this purple color in Color.kt. I believe it is the default color from Theme.Material3.DayNight.

[image]

[Update]
I get rid of purple title bar by replacing parent sytle Theme.Material3.DayNight with Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Bridge. Not sure if there better way to handle it.